# Angular disableAutoScrolling not working with html5mode navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app I'm changing location hash `#` when page scrolls down. When top part of `div` element with `id` e.g. `section-1` appears on screen, I'm changing hash via `$location.$hash()` method.

To prevent autoscroll browser behavior, I use `disableAutoScrolling`. When html5mode is disabled, all works as expected and page doesn't scroll automatically on hash change. But when I enable html5mode it ignores `disableAutoScrolling` and scrolls page to element on location hash change event.

Here's a part of code that is responsible for html5mode and autoScroll prevention.

```
app.config(['$anchorScrollProvider' , '$locationProvider', function ($anchorScrollProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

For now i see the only workaround - append some additional character to `div` ids, to avoid this scroll.

Angular 1.3.8 (1.3.5 also have this) + angular-ui-router 0.2.13 (0.2.11 also have this).

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks.